# make a table with flexible column count

Tags: tables, foreach

I have a file which I would like to be able to generate two documents, one with narrow pages and one with wide pages. I have a figure in the document with several narrow equations, and to save space in the wide document, I would like to put them side by side. So, ideally, the output would look something like this in the wide document:

```
a = foo    wx = bar
b = baz    yz = quux
```

and like this in the narrow document:

```
a  = foo
b  = baz
wx = bar
yz = quux
```

Of particular import: I'd like the equals signs to align in the narrow document, and each column of the wide document should stick together (e.g. the ordering "a, wx, b, yz" in the narrow document would be less preferable). I had an idea that I could do this using `tikz`'s `\foreach`; an attempt that cuts out as many irrelevant details as possible follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\newcommand{\makeatable}[1]{\begin{tabular}{lr}#1\end{tabular}}
\newcommand\sidebyside[1]{\foreach \l/\r in {#1}{\l & \r\\}}
\newcommand\toptobottom[1]{%
    \foreach \t/\b in {#1}{\t\\}
    \foreach \t/\b in {#1}{\b\\}
}

\newcommand\contents{{foo/bar},{baz/quux}}
\makeatable{\sidebyside \contents}
\makeatable{\toptobottom\contents}
\end{document}
```

Unfortunately emitting `&` or `\\` from a `\foreach` seems to cause problems (there are dozens of errors; I'll be happy to include a transcript if that seems helpful).

Is there a way to make this work with `\foreach`? Or, what other things could I try?

Comment: You could just use align and put it in multicols, no neec to break by hand

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\allowdisplaybreaks
\begin{document}

one
\begin{align}
a  &= foo\\
b  &= baz\\
wx &= bar\\
yz &= quux
\end{align}


two
\begin{multicols}{2}
\vspace*{-3\baselineskip}
\begin{align}
a  &= foo\\*
b  &= baz\\
wx &= bar\\
yz &= quux
\end{align}
\end{multicols}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my test, the multicols environment won't work from within an array, so this won't work for me. But this seems like the right answer given the information in my original question, so I'll accept it.

Comment: @DanielWagner not sure what you mean but multicolmns is a vertical mode environment you can use it in an array if you really want so long as you are in a vertical mode cell so `p{..}` not `c`